# stripping seconds from time data in R

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
y<-c("00:00:10", "00:10:10", "2:10:2")
```

These data are in H:M:S format. I would like to be able to convert this data to total seconds. I like to get H data multiply that with H*60*60 + M*60 + S to calculate the value in total seconds.

I was doing this:

```
z <- strptime(, "%H")
```

to get the Hour value, not working. Can anybody chime in?

Comment: I'm sure this isn't robust, but it follows what you were trying: `as.numeric(format(strptime(y, "%H"), "%H"))`

Comment: GSee I get NA when I do this.

Comment: really? I get `0 0 2`.  Well, I told you it wasn't robust. ;-)

Comment: The answer is always `require(lubridate)`   :-).  It's a very handy package of date / time tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never gotten the hang of handling time in with sophisticated packages. Here's a oneliner that does it instead.

```
> apply(sweep(sapply(strsplit(y, ":"), as.integer), 1, 60^(2:0), "*"), 2, sum)
[1]   10  610 7802
```

Comment: How odd, it works fine for me. Just double checked it too. Could someone else check it perhaps? I am using the same `y` you defined in your question.

Comment: I checked it, works great and has already replaced my old code.  Very slick solution!

Answer (score 3):

Can your hours go past 24?  If so, I think you have to treat these as strings.  Also in your example, what does the last `2` mean in the third time `2:10:2`?  Is that two seconds or twenty?

I use these two functions to convert back and forth:

```
convertSecToHrMinSec <- function(vec) {
  # takes a vector of seconds
  # returns string formatted as HHH:MM:SS
  vec <- as.integer(vec)
  hr  <- floor(vec / 3600)
  min <- floor((vec - hr * 3600) / 60)
  sec <- vec - min * 60 - hr * 3600
  hr  <- sprintf('%02d', hr)
  min <- sprintf('%02d', min)
  sec <- sprintf('%02d', sec)

  return (paste(hr, min, sec, sep=':'))
}

convertHrMinSecToSec <- function(vec) {
  ## convert hrs:mins:seconds to seconds
  require(stringr)
  require(plyr)
  if (length(grep('.+/.+:.+', vec, perl=TRUE)) >= 1) return(vec)
  if (length(grep('.+:.+:.+', vec, perl=TRUE)) >= 1) {
    vec <- laply(str_split(vec, ':'), function(x) as.integer(x[1]) * 3600 + as.integer(x[2]) * 60 + as.integer(x[3]))
  }

  return (vec)
}
```

---

As per Carl's comment above using `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
hms(y)

[1] 10 seconds                         10 minutes and 10 seconds          2 hours, 10 minutes and 2 seconds
```

And for good measure:

```
> str(hms(y))
Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  ..@ .Data : num [1:3] 10 10 2
  ..@ year  : num [1:3] 0 0 0
  ..@ month : num [1:3] 0 0 0
  ..@ day   : num [1:3] 0 0 0
  ..@ hour  : num [1:3] 0 0 2
  ..@ minute: num [1:3] 0 10 10
>
```

The `period` type that Hadley created in `lubridate` is very pleasant to work with, but does require a little getting used to.

Comment: @GSee where am I missing it?  I have a bunch of packages loading in my .Rprofile. Feel free to edit!

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to the party, but I think is a good way to do it because it uses the standard time functions and it is dead simple:

```
as.integer(as.POSIXct(y,format="%H:%M:%S",tz="GMT")) %% (60*60*24)
```

`[1]   10  610 7802`

Note: this is only applicable if your data are clock times.

Comment: This is a great solution so long as you are sure your hours will not go above 23 and the minutes and seconds will be less than 60.  I regularly get reports in hundreds of hours.

Comment: @justin that is a good point. This assumes these are clock times. I have edited to note this.